# tkinter elements not resizing with window, using pack

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the current code below for some basic parameter entry into an AI assignment. It is just there to st the starting parameters and display the outpit of the different algorithms implemented, however the box that contains the output will not resize? I think I am doing something wrong with maybe the parent-child structure but I can't figure out what.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.mainframe= tk.Frame(master=self, width=768, height=576)
    self.mainframe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.xsizelabel = tk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Size (X)")
    self.xsizelabel.pack(side="top")
    self.xsize = tk.Entry(self.mainframe)
    self.xsize.insert(0, 2)
    self.xsize.pack(side="top")
    self.ysizelabel = tk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Size (Y)")
    self.ysizelabel.pack(side="top")
    self.ysize = tk.Entry(self.mainframe)
    self.ysize.insert(0, 1)
    self.ysize.pack(side="top")
    self.xstartlabel = tk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Starting Position (X)")
    self.xstartlabel.pack(side="top")
    self.xStart = tk.Entry(self.mainframe)
    self.xStart.insert(0, 0)
    self.xStart.pack(side="top")
    self.ystartlabel = tk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Starting Position (Y)")
    self.ystartlabel.pack(side="top")
    self.yStart = tk.Entry(self.mainframe)
    self.yStart.insert(0, 0)
    self.yStart.pack(side="top")
    self.outputstartlabel = tk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Output")
    self.outputstartlabel.pack(side="top")
    self.separator = tk.Frame(master=self.mainframe, width=768, height=576, bd=1)
    self.separator.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.output = tk.Scrollbar(self.separator)
    self.output.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.separator, yscrollcommand=self.output.set)
    self.listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.run_button = tk.Button(self.mainframe)
    self.run_button["text"] = "Run with these settings"
    self.run_button["command"] = self.runAlgorithm
    self.run_button.pack(side="top")
    self.quit = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")
```

but the resulting window looks like this:
[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNVDg.png)

[expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SeZf.png)

nothing expands when I expand the window, dispite setting the autofill and expand options. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you even using tkinter?

Comment: @RandomChannel That's not a helpful comment.  Tkinter is quite useful in certain situations and is also a good learning tool.

Comment: @RandomChannel: tkinter is a fantastic learning tool, and the perfect toolkit for many types of programs.

Comment: Its a helpful learning tool, but its not meant for that this person is asking.

Comment: I am using tkinter because i needed to slap a quick gui on a python project. the goal of the project is to set up efficiency grading of different algorithms, but the requirements said "Please have a GUI for parameter input". I am pretty decently versed in python for backend stuff, but haven't used a GUI with it before, I am primarily a webapp coder. google said tkinter was the fastest way to make a GUI in python so that's what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your program because you didn't present the whole thing.  I see that you have set the fill and expand options on self.mainframe, but you didn't set those options in the constructor.  Therefore the base window, which contains self.mainframe, will not expand to fill its available space.  You need to make all the parent windows expandable, because when you drag the edges of the main window you are acting on the top level frame.

Comment: thanks, I figured it had something to do with the parent frame but completely missed that I didn't set it expandable in the constructor